# DataFrame column stores lists of dictionaries as strings: Parse it and build a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, dictionary

I have a huge dataframe (2 million rows) in which a certain column has a string representations of a list of dictionaries (it is the school history of several people). So, what I'm trying to do is parsing this data to a new dataframe (because the relation is going to be 1 person to many schools).

However, my first option was to loop over the dataframe with `itertuples()`. Too slow!

The first few rows look like this:

```
list_of_dicts = {
    0: '[]',
    1: "[{'name': 'USA Health', 'subject': 'Residency, Internal Medicine, 2006 - 2009'}, {'name': 'Ross University School of Medicine', 'subject': 'Class of 2005'}]",
    2: "[{'name': 'Physicians Medical Center Carraway', 'subject': 'Residency, Surgery, 1957 - 1960'}, {'name': 'Physicians Medical Center Carraway', 'subject': 'Internship, Transitional Year, 1954 - 1955'}, {'name': 'University of Alabama School of Medicine', 'subject': 'Class of 1954'}]"
}

df_dict = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(list_of_dicts, orient='index', columns=['school_history'])
```

What I thought about, was to have a function and then apply it to the dataframe:

```
def parse_item(row):
    eval_dict = eval(row)[0]
    school_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(eval_dict, orient='index').T
    return school_df

df['column'].apply(lambda x: parse_item(x))
```

However, I'm not able to figure out how to generate a dataframe bigger than original (due to situations of multiple schools to one person).

From those 3 rows, the idea is to have this dataframe (that has 5 rows from 2 rows):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the trick using your sample data (thanks for the performance tip in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73793168/parse-a-list-of-dictionaries-with-apply-lambda/73793315#comment130303862_73793315)):

```py
list_df = df_dict.school_history.map(ast.literal_eval)
exploded = list_df[list_df.str.len() > 0].explode()
final = pd.DataFrame(list(exploded), index=exploded.index)
```

This produces the following:

```py
In [54]: final
Out[54]:
                                       name                                     subject
1                                USA Health   Residency, Internal Medicine, 2006 - 2009
1        Ross University School of Medicine                               Class of 2005
2        Physicians Medical Center Carraway             Residency, Surgery, 1957 - 1960
2        Physicians Medical Center Carraway  Internship, Transitional Year, 1954 - 1955
2  University of Alabama School of Medicine                               Class of 1954
```

This will probably not be super fast given the amount of data, but parsing a dictionary of strings with nested objects inside will probably be pretty slow no matter what. You're probably better off parsing the file upstream first, then converting to pandas.

Answer (score 3):

Iterate over the column to convert each string into a python list using `ast.literal_eval()`; the result is a nested list, which can be flattened inside the same comprehension.

N.B. Converting the column to a list (via `tolist()`) first sees some performance gain.

```py
from ast import literal_eval
result = pd.DataFrame([x 
                       for row in df_dict['school_history'].tolist() 
                       for x in literal_eval(row)])
```

To retain the original index, instead of iterating over the column as a list, iterate over the zip object created by calling `items()` method on it. This returns `(index, value)` tuples where the indexes may be attached to the final output values.

```
ind, data = zip(*[(i, x) 
                  for i, row in df_dict['school_history'].items() 
                  for x in ast.literal_eval(row)]);
result = pd.DataFrame(data, index=ind)
```

[image: res]